# Oracle node to connect with the NYSE

Tags: oracles

Does exist an oracle that it’s able to connect with the NYSE or others stock markets?
If so, could you please tell me which?

Answer (score 1):

Pyth offers [equity price feeds](https://pyth.network/price-feeds?asset-type=equity).

Note that they do not automatically offer you every stock: you might need to request and pay for new price feeds.